# Access elements of a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am getting a compiler error on something I thought was very straight forward and I don't fully understand. I have a 2D array and I want to compare one of the elements to another in a switch case.

```
#define REV_1    {'A','B','C','D'}
#define REV_2    {'E','F','G','H'}
#define REV_3    {'I','J','K','L'}
void myfunction()
{
    char Revisions[3][4] = {REV_1,REV_2,REV_3};
    char Rev1FirstLetter = Revisions[0][0];
    char Rev2FirstLetter = Revisions[1][0];
    char Rev3FirstLetter = Revisions[2][0];

    char doesntmatter = 5;
    switch(doesntmatter)
    {
        case Rev1FirstLetter:
        {
            [....]
            break;
        }
        case Rev2FirstLetter:
        {
            [....]
            break;
        }
        case Rev2FirstLetter:
        {
            [....]
            break;         
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting compiler errors saying

```
Error: #268: declaration may not appear after executable statement in block
```

on the lines

```
char Rev1FirstLetter = Revisions[0][0];
char Rev2FirstLetter = Revisions[1][0];
char Rev3FirstLetter = Revisions[2][0];
```

So do I have to use a pointer plus an offset to access these elements? I know you can assign values INTO the array like

```
Revisions[0][1] = 'F';
```

but I always thought that you could read values out of an array in the same way. Sorry for the beginner question, but could someone please explain to me what the best way to access the data in this 2D array would be, whether it requires a pointer and offset, or another method?

Comment: What compiler/platform are you using?

Comment: I am using armcc compiler, running on windows 7 machine

Comment: If what you've posted is what you're actually compiling, that error doesn't make sense; you don't have any executable statements preceding your declarations.  Make sure that you've accurately copied and pasted the code you're trying to compile.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the exact code because it's confidential, but your comment definitely helped solve the problem! It turns out the compiler actually doesn't allow you to declare variables after an executable statement. I did not fully understand what that meant when I read it on my compiler output for some reason. I moved the declaration to the top of the function and it no longer gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Assignments are ok. However, there is an issue with switch statement since case values are not constant expressions. 
If I change case values to constant expressions i.e. 'A', 'B' it compiles with c99 flag.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `constexpr` is a C++11 feature. And the question is tagged C, not C++.

Comment: Even when I remove the case statement I am getting the same Error: #268: declaration may not appear after executable statement in block. So it is definitely a problem with the char Rev1FirstLetter = Revisions[0][0];

Comment: So now I realize that I simply had to declare the variables prior to any executable statement and solved that problem. But now I see the problem you are talking about Blaz. So there is no way for me to use the members of a char array as the cases in the switch? I am getting Error: #259: constant value is not known